# How to get pull requester e-mail in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm using [Bitbucket Push and Pull Request](https://plugins.jenkins.io/bitbucket-push-and-pull-request/) plugin to trigger pipeline via webhook when pull request is open or updated in
BitBucket repo.

Now I want to send a mail notification to pull requestor about the pipeline execution.

Additionally to that I want to send same kind of notification when the PR is merged to the the requester and merger.

```
post {
    always {
        emailext body: 'Test Message',
            subject: 'Test Subject',
            to: '${prRecipient}'
    }
}
```

My question is how to get the e-mail address of the requestor and set it as value **prRecipient** in the example of the code above?

**BitBucket is a server, not Cloud!**

Answer (score 0):

I
was able to achieve this whit emailext plugin and **recipientProviders** like that:

```
post {
    always {
        emailext to: "default@mail.com"
                 body: 'A Test EMail', 
                 recipientProviders: [[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']],
                 subject: 'Test'
    }
}
```